# Converting web.config file to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis, web-config, web.config-transform

Can anybody help me to convert this web.config file to .htaccess

I can find several online converters for .htaccess to web.config but none for web.config to .htaccess

```
<rules>
    <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^themes/sets\.cfm$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^set=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="themes/sets/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^themes/sets/([^/]+)/?$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="themes/sets.cfm?theme={R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^set\.cfm$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^set=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;name=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="set/{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^set/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="set.cfm?set={R:1}&amp;name={R:2}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't seem that big, why not convert it by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised your "friendly url 2" block didn't produce an infinite redirect loop (maybe IIS takes care of this itself, i don't know).

Anyway, with Apache and `mod_rewrite`, you would have an infinite loop by just "translating" your rules.

Note: "friendly url 1" can be translated as is, since redirect and rewrite are not exactly for the same target).

Here is how your htaccess should look like

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews

# RedirectUserFriendlyURL1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^set=([^&=]+)$
RewriteRule ^themes/sets\.cfm$ /themes/sets/%1? [R=301,L]

# RewriteUserFriendlyURL1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^themes/sets/([^/]+)/?$ /themes/sets.cfm?theme=$1 [L]

# RedirectUserFriendlyURL2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/set\.cfm\?set=([^&\s]+)&name=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /set/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# RewriteUserFriendlyURL2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^set/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /set.cfm?set=$1&name=$2 [L]
```